# Automatically retrieve video thumbnails from other sites

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, thumbnails

I'm currently making a website that displays links to videos from another website. I already created the layout of the site. However, I find it tedious to capture a still image of a video just to add a thumbnail unto my website. Is there a way to retrieve video thumbnails automatically when links are added to the site?

I saw a few PHP codes that do it but are meant strictly for Youtube. My source of videos for my site however is different. Can someone please assist by posting an example of the code and how/where to place it in the site (PHP file / CSS). I'm not a professional web developer so I would better understand with an example. Java script would be great if possible.

Comment: if the other site already shows thumbnails, you might be able to scrape them. if you have to make your own, it's complicated and takes human effort.

Comment: The site makes its own. Am I able to somehow get them to display on my site?

Comment: 9/10 times you can just set your img tag to the image's path on the remote site and it will show up. of course, you need to know the path of the image and what video it's associated with, but if you're grabbing videos already, you can handle images... you should also check that you don't violate a policy by deeplinking or exporting their thumbnails.

Comment: I was hoping to add a line of code and call it a day. *sigh Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Most video websites have a similar naming scheme for their generated thumbnails. Let's look at dailymotion.com for an example:

Video embed link:
http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x13meal

Video thumbnail link:
http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/x13meal

They both have the video ID x13meal at the end. So if you have the link to the video, you also have a link to its thumbnail.

Comment: Same is true for Youtube and MetaCafe. You'll just need to setup the URL's with the var containing that ID in a switch/array for each provider.

Comment: Thanks dude(s). It wasn't what I was looking for but good enough. 

What I really wanted to do is retrieve thumbnails automatically in real time. E.g. when you post a link on Facebook, the thumbnail is automatically retrieved and posted. 

This will have to do for now. Better than taking still snapshots of videos.